# Page section with multiple questions with "Go to page based on answer" redirections, is it possible?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-forms

I have a section of a form which asks the users several questions which contains "Go to page based on answer" redirections.

I would like the form to cycle through the redirects in order, but it only does the last redirection.

For example

#### Fruit Bowl

Q1. Do you like Apples?
      
Yes - Go to 'Apple Questions' Section
      
No

Q2. Do you like Oranges?
      
Yes - Go to 'Orange Questions' Section 
      No

Q3. Do you like Bananas?
      
Yes - Go to 'Banana Questions' Section
      
No

---

Currently if a user says yes to all 3 questions, they get directed to the 'Banana Questions' section and then to the end of the form.

I would like it so if a user says yes to more than one question they do each extra section in turn...for example if they tick yes to all three the user will be taken to the 'Apple Questions' then 'Orange Questions' then 'Banana Questions' sections before finishing to form.

The only way round this I can find is having each question in a separate page...which would be terrible for the user.

Can this be achieved in Google Forms? If not, does anyone know of any free form alternatives which feed into Google Drive?

Thanks for your help

Martyn

Comment: I was just going to ask this same question. Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: Would like to know the same

Comment: To ask for software recommendations try [softwarerecs.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Form doesn't include a way to do this but this is possible and there are many ways to do this.

One alternative is to use the old Google Forms with a Google Apps Script that use UrlFetchApp to get and post the source code of each page.

The broad steps of another alternative is described on https://web.archive.org/web/20170110084811/http://morning.am/tutorials/how-to-style-google-forms-redux/. Once you get your form working, you could tweak the form logic by using jQuery.